# Override [AnyObject]? array in parent class in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a `ParentController` and `ChildController` as below. The ParentController holds an array of `[AnyObject]?` and the child class holds an array of specific models (i.e. `Merchant`). The parent class has methods that references the `results` array, hence I've declared it as `[AnyObject]?`.

Is there a way that I can override the `results` array in `ChildController`?

Rationale: I had tried `results.append()` originally in `ChildController`, but apparently that causes issues due to downcasting. The problem was sporadic, so hard to explain. However, after about a week of research and trial & error, I think the only way to solve this is to create a separate array in the `ChildController` to hold data, but still be accessible by methods in the parent class. Thoughts?

```
class ParentClass: UIViewController {
    var results: [AnyObject]?

    //has methods that reference results array
}

class ChildClass: ParentClass {

    var merchants: [Merchant]?
    override var results: [AnyObject]? {
        get {
            return self.merchants as [AnyObject]?   
            //this doesn't work, gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
        }
        set {
            super.results = self.merchants as [AnyObject]?
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate that please? do you want to override the property and change it's type?

Comment: Have you tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/24094339/1187415? Can you provide a self-contained example that causes the crash?