# Overriding Swift property with descendant subclass

Tags: swift, properties, overriding

I'd like to override descendant property, because I want to use methods from `TestViewModel` class directly without casting `ViewModel` to `TestViewModel`.
As I suppose it's not possible. Could you advise some nice solution. Code and error below:

```
class ViewModel {
}

class View: UIView {
    weak var viewModel: ViewModel!
}

class TestViewModel {
}

class TestView: View {
    weak var viewModel: TestViewModel! // error here
}
```

Got this error:

> /Users/evgeniirtishchev/Documents/Development/rdfuturesales/RDProject/View/Identification/IdentificationView.swift:12:26:
>   Cannot override mutable property 'viewModel' of type 'ViewModel!' with
>   covariant type 'IdentificationViewModel!'

Comment: Did you mean `class TestView: View` above? (Rather than `... : UIView`).

Comment: @dfri yes, sorry, typo

Answer (score 3):

Swift does not allow you to change the class type of any variables or properties.

See related question: [Overriding superclass property with different type in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift)