# Swift and property inheritance from superclass

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift2

I have A class. And its subclass B. I need to override type of its property.  Also that will be ok to to change a protocol.  How can I do that?

```
class A {
 var property: String (or SomeProtocolA)
}

class B: A {
 var property: Int (or SomeProtocolB)
}
```

Maybe its possible to add support second protocol for  property in subclass?

Comment: You can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift

Comment: One rule of OO inheritance is that B is substitutable for A -- meaning if I think I have an A, but really have a B, it's ok.  B can do everything A can do and hare no extra requirements.  So B.property needs to be String or behave like String.

Comment: In your real example, does SomeProtocolB inherit from SomeProtocolA?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and this is indicative of poor design.

Suppose Class A had a function:

```
class A {
    var property: String (or SomeProtocolA)

    func getMyString() -> String {
        return property
    }
}
```

and now class B inherits it, whilst "overwriting" `property`:

```
class B : A {
    var property: Int(or SomeProtocolB)

    // func getMyString() -> String { //inherited from superclass
    //    return property //type error, expected String, returning Int
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but in **VERY** limited situations. The only ways that this is allowed is under the following circumstances:

1. The property must be `get` only.
2. The overriding type must be a subclass of the original type (so no `struct`, `protocol` or `enum`).

Here is an example overriding with strings:

```
class A {
    var property: NSString {
        return ""
    }
} 

class B: A {
    override var property: NSMutableString {
        return NSMutableString(string: "")
    }
}
```