# Polymorphism when overriding methods or properties in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to ensure by compiler that `CarViewController` only receives a `Car` in the vehicle property.

Given the following swift example code:

```
class Vehicle {
    func doSomething(){}
}

class Car: Vehicle {
    func doCarThings(){}
}

class VehicleViewController : UIViewController {
    var vehicle : Vehicle!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        vehicle.doSomething();
    }
}

class CarViewController:VehicleViewController {
    var vehicle: Car!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        vehicle.doCarThings();
    }
}
```

I get the  following error: `Cannot override mutable property 'vehicle' of type 'Vehicle!' with covariant type 'Car!'`

I tried with a generics-based approach:

```
class Vehicle {
    func doSomething(){}
}

class Car: Vehicle {
    func doCarThings(){}
}

class VehicleViewController<T:Vehicle> : UIViewController {
    var vehicle : T!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        vehicle.doSomething();
    }
}

class CarViewController:VehicleViewController<Car> {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        vehicle.doCarThings();
    }
}
```

It is correct but using generics in storyboard classes results in errors (since they get compiled to objective-c).

How can I do this without using generics?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible Dublicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure about the design here, but to accomplish what you want you could do:

```
class CarViewController: VehicleViewController {
    var vehicleAsCar: Car { return self.vehicle as! Car }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        vehicleAsCar.doCarThings();
    }
}
```

But this seems very smelly. Safer night be:

```
class CarViewController: VehicleViewController {
    override var vehicle: Vehicle! {
        didSet {
            assert(vehicle is Car, "Attempt to set vehicle to non-Car")
        }
    }
    var vehicleAsCar: Car { return self.vehicle as! Car }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        vehicleAsCar.doCarThings();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html):

Overriding Property Getters and Setters

> You can provide a custom getter (and setter, if appropriate) to
> override any inherited property, regardless of whether the inherited
> property is implemented as a stored or computed property at source.
> The stored or computed nature of an inherited property is not known by
> a subclass—it only knows that the inherited property has a certain
> name and type. You must always state both the name and the type of the
> property you are overriding, to enable the compiler to check that your
> override matches a superclass property with the same name and type.

Seems like you cant do that.