# Override @IBoutlet property with different type of compatible class

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I have @IBOutlet var **heading** of type UILabel in base class, now I subclassed this and in the new class I want to have @IBoutlet **heading** of type `MyLabel` (let's say I have a class `MyLabel` subclassed from UILabel). So the question is: how to override the same property to different compatible class?

Comment: you can cast it as `MyLabel`  if is a subclass and your IBOutlet class in storyboard is correct you can't have any problems

Comment: Goto storyboard select label - > set class to MyLabel -> Connect IBOutlet you done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift

This can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to override property with different type. You can change a class of this property in the Interface Builder and make another property with needed class:

```
@IBOutlet override var label: UILabel!

private var myLabel: MyLabel? {
    return label as? MyLabel
}
```