# Override property with different type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I want to implement the approach used by `UITableView`.

I have subclass `UITableView` with my own class `FloatingTableView` I want to override the `delegate` of `UITableView` which is `UITableViewDelegate` with my `delegate` of type `FloatingTableViewDelegate` just the way `UITableView` inherit from `UIScrollView` and override the `UIScrollViewDelegate` with `UITableViewDelegate` both class have same property with name `delegate` but have different types.

I have also tried to inherit my protocol with `UITableViewDelegate`
But when i try to create property with name `delegate` of type `FloatingTableViewDelegate` I get this error..

> Property 'delegate' with type 'MyTableViewDelegate?' cannot override a
>   property with type 'UITableViewDelegate?'

**Here is my sample code.**

```
protocol MyTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
    func isDemoDelegateMethod()
}

class MyTableView: UITableView {
    weak var delegate: MyTableViewDelegate?
}
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift/24094339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works for Objective C is because of the dynamic nature of the language. You can redeclare the type of super class and instead of synthesizing the property you would make it a dynamic type, which would let you redeclare it.

```
@protocol MyTableViewDelegate<UITableViewDelegate>

- (void)demoDelegateMethod;

@end


@interface WrapperTableView: UITableView

@property (nonatomic, weak, nullable) id <MyTableViewDelegate> delegate;


@end

@implementation WrapperTableView

@dynamic delegate;

@end
```

But, I doubt this would be possible with Swift, since, you are changing the type completely. It is because of Swift being strong static language.

**Answer Edited**

I got your approach. I write above approach in `Objective-C` and then inherit this class in `Swift`.
So if I have to override SuperClass property with different type I need to create a wrapper class in `Objective-C` inherit from desired `SuperClass` and then finally instead of inheriting directly from desired super class I should inherit from the newly created `WrapperClass` which is written in `Objective-C`

```
class MyTableView: WrapperTableView {
    //Now Here the delegate object is of type MyTableViewDelegate
}
```

This approach is far better then

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {
   private var myDelegate: MyTableViewDelegate?
   override var delegate: UITableViewDelegate { 
        set{
            myDelegate = newValue
        }
        get{
            return myDelegate
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: What is tableview doing ?

Comment: So this approach is not possible in `Swift`?

Comment: How does `UITableView` did this?

Comment: I told you UITableView does this with Objective C being the nature of the language. Look at MyTableView above with Objective C, that is completely valid with ObjC. Not with Swift

Comment: I am up voting your answer because you have provide me an idea to achieve above goal in `Swifty-Objc` approach.