# Overriding superclass property with different type

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

The following code throws an error

```
protocol WhatA: AnyObject {
    func doThat()
}

protocol WhatB: WhatA {
    func doThis()
}

class SomethingA {
    weak var delegate: WhatA?
}

class SomethingB: SomethingA {
    weak var delegate: WhatB?
}
```

> Property 'delegate' with type 'WhatB?' cannot override a property with
>   type 'WhatA?'

UIKit has no problems with the following

```
open class UIScrollView : UIView, NSCoding, UIFocusItemScrollableContainer {

    weak open var delegate: UIScrollViewDelegate?

}

open class UITableView : UIScrollView, NSCoding, UIDataSourceTranslating {

    weak open var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?

}
```

Why does this work in UIKit? The accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift) question suggests this is not possible.

Comment: You can not able to override in UIKit as well you can try it once more time

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh Can you please clarify your comment.

Comment: I suggest reading up on this topic here: https://forums.swift.org/t/in-a-sub-class-is-it-possible-to-override-a-property-of-the-super-class-and-constrain-to-a-sub-type-of-the-original-property/10747 . TL;DR: It's unsafe Objective-C magic that you can't do in Swift.

Comment: Thanks @TylerTheCompiler will accept if made official answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to post it as an answer because it was just a link. @rmaddy 's answer actually explains it, which is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it works with `UIScrollView` and `UITableView` and their delegates is that they are generated Swift interfaces from the original Objective-C headers.

Objective-C lets you do this. While you can't create Swift classes that do this directly, Swift class interfaces generated from an Objective-C bridging header can result is the case you see here.

Comment: Adding the link provided by @TylerTheCompiler in comments for completion https://forums.swift.org/t/in-a-sub-class-is-it-possible-to-override-a-property-of-the-super-class-and-constrain-to-a-sub-type-of-the-original-property/10747/5