# How can subclass override a property from parent class in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I want to have a property in BaseClass which is an array of type anything which extends Movable and in subclass I want to override the same property with type Transportable which extends Movable.

How do we declare "anything which extends Movable" in Swift?

```swift
protocol Movable{
    func move()
}

struct Transportable : Movable{
    func transport()
}

class BaseClass{
    var myProperty: [Movable] = []
}

class MyClass: BaseClass{
    override var myProperty = [Transportable]()
}
```

It doesn't compile and gives me an error:

> Property 'myProperty' with type '[Transportable]' cannot override a property with type '[Movable]'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding superclass property with different type in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift)

Comment: Better to use generics here

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am new to generics. Can you please show me how generics will solve this?

Comment: Define the base class as `class BaseClass<T: Movable>{
    var myProperty: [T] = []
}` and then remove the property from the sub class and change the definition of it to `class MyClass: BaseClass<Transportable>`